# Gatling not picking up actions once on portal

Tags: gatling

Not sure why this is happening but when using the recorder it stops recording immediately after typing in the target address.  Once inside the portal it no longer records any actions.  Does this have to do with the web address being on https?  What actions should I take in order to utilize the recording tool?

Comment: You'd have to provide more information, or a way to reproduce.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To answer my own question I had to access the 1.5.6 documentation.  It talked about how to properly setup firefox network connections for interacting within https environment.

This is how it should look.  This affects working within any HTTPS environment

[image: Proxy Configuration For Gatling.io]

Comment: Everything's in there in the current documentation. From quickstart: "... and configure your browser to use Gatling Recorder’s proxy. For more information regarding Recorder and browser configuration, please check out Recorder reference page." Then: http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.4/http/recorder.html#recorder

Comment: Its in the 1.5.6 documentation.  Not the current.  The images do not line up with what the downloadable file is and what the documentation says.

Comment: Stop referring to old dropped 1.5.6 and properly read the doc!!! You'll find the same kind of image in there: http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.4/http/recorder.html#listening-proxy-port

Comment: Hey now don't get mad.  The documentation isn't the same.   I'm sorry 2.1.4 does not reflect  the same interface for the recorder that 1.5.6 documentation does.  Even through the download link is supposedly for the 2.1.4.